# How to display a series of actions that occur over a timespan?

Tags: c#, excel, graph, charts, timespan

I have a set of actions that occurred in the form of start time, end time:

```
Action1, 2011/09/04 8:37:22 AM, 2011/09/04 8:38:37 AM
Action2, 2011/09/04 8:37:55 AM, 2011/09/04 8:38:05 AM
Action3, 2011/09/04 8:38:12 AM, 2011/09/04 8:38:35 AM
Action4, 2011/09/04 8:38:57 AM, 2011/09/04 8:39:56 AM
```

I want to display these in a chart that can visually depict which actions were running at which time, so I can identify if there were periods where, say, 50 actions were happening at the same time, and if that led to a CPU spike (I have perfmon data from this as well, but I can do that portion manually).

I am very familiar with C#, so if there are any charting libraries or controls for this, I can use that with some guidance. Even Excel would work for my purpose, but I can't figure out how to visually display this.

Comment: How many actions are we talking about here? And are you just interested in the count of actions running at time t, or also in seeing what specific actions were running?

Comment: during any one time, up to 50 actions. during the whole day, maybe 1000. also interested in knowing what actions were occuring during the time range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a timeline view like this one: http://nicolas.kruchten.com/content/2010/09/context/ (link to an old project of mine). It scales pretty well to 1000 time-ranges where 50 might occur simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Visifire is a charting library which works with Silverlight and WPF (your C# requirement).
I think this [DOCUMENTATION LINK](http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Core_Concepts/Working_with_Date_and_Time/Managed_Code_Sample.htm) should be useful in addressing your issue.